# Is it legal to buy things internationally for Bitcoin from India?

Tags: legal

I want to buy educational videos from someone in the USA, who offers them privately for sale as a digital download. He accepts Bitcoin.

I'm purchasing them from India.

**Would it be legal for me to buy from him in this fashion?**

Comment: We're not your lawyers and can't offer you legal advice.  However, lots of people do this all the time.